# Export with different type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to export under a different type?

I have a module, which exports an object, which may change. Internal access to the object should be more permissive than external:

```
// Module A.
export let o = {
  publiclyAvailable: 0,
  noTouchy: 0,
};

const f = () => { o.noTouchy; /* Ok. */ };
const g = () => { /* reassign `o` */ };

// Module B.
import { o } from './A.js';
o.publiclyAvailable; // Ok.
// o.noTouchy; // No!
```

What i am currently using is a useless indirection and code bleeding into emit:

```
// Module A.
let oContainer = {
  _realO: {
     publiclyAvailable: 0,
     noTouchy: 0,
  },
  get o() { return this._realO; },
  set o(v) {
    this._realO = v;
    o = v;
  },
};
export let o: { publiclyAvailable: number } = oContainer.o;
```

but obviously, writing `oContainer.o` every time serves no purpose at all.

There is also a trick of asserting, but that only works on the top level:

```
// Module A.
const hax: (x: typeof o) => asserts x is { publiclyAvailable: number; noTouchy: number } = () => void 0;
export let o: {
  publiclyAvailable: number
} = (() => ({
  publiclyAvailable: 0,
  noTouchy: 0,
}))();
hax(o);
o.noTouchy; // Works!
const f = () => { o.noTouchy; /* Fails. */ };
```

---

Edit: Thought of a less cumbersome way (which however still bleeds into emit for no reason):

```
// Module A.
let _o = {
  publiclyAvailable: 0,
  noTouchy: 0,
}
export const o = new Proxy({} as { publiclyAvailable: number }, {
  get(_, p: keyof typeof _o) { return _o[p]; },
  /* ... all other handlers, cause that's what `Proxy` needs ... */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) as the property key and simply not export it.

```js
// file: person.js

const ageSymbol = Symbol('age');

// export
const john = {
  name: 'John',
  // ...
  [ageSymbol]: 20,
}

console.log('person.js:', 'age is', john[ageSymbol])

// file: main.js

// can't access ageSymbol since it's not exported
// if you try to create a new symbol, it won't work

console.log('main.js:', 'age is', john[Symbol('age')])
```

The real question is: Why would you want this?
If you intend to create a sort of library, add documentation for that object / property saying that it is private. If you're using Typescript, cast your object to an interface that doesn't have that field.

Here's a javascript example:

```js
export const myObject = {
  data: {},
  /** @private */
  __myPrivateProperty: true
};
```

Here's a typescript example:

```
interface MyInterfaceWithSecret {
  data: any;
  secret: string;
}

export type MyInterfaceWithHiddenSecret = Omit<MyInterfaceWithSecret, 'secret'>;
// or
export interface MyInterfaceWithHiddenSecret {
  data: any;
}


const mySecretObject: MyInterfaceWithSecret {
  data: {},
  secret: 'shhh'
};

export const myPublicObject = mySecretObject as MyInterfaceWithHiddenSecret
```

Comment: I maybe wasn't explicit enough on "may change" - the `let` isn't optional, see `const g = () => { /* reassign o */ };`. That's exactly the issue, why i can't do your typescript suggestion, the variables cannot be `const`, and reassigning one would have to change the other.